# Modify the HTML of a servlet's errorPage from a Filter

Tags: java, servlets, exception

I have a requirement to rewrite HTML generated by a web application. The requirement applies to all pages equally so naturally we went for a Filter.

I cribbed the stream wrapping approach from this [Oracle documentation on filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html#72674) and this works for most cases. Unfortunately, if the servlet throws an exception the flow of execution leaves my filter and the rewriting logic is not executed. This means the HTML of error pages is not modified.

I want to intercept the error page response as well. How do I do that?

Comment: Which app-server, and is your error page static HTML or a JSP?

Comment: Tomcat 7. It's a static HTML file, but due to some URL mapping issues it's served through Spring MVC's ResourceHttpRequestHandler in a separate instance of DispatcherServlet.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `filter-mapping`:

```
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
```